# How to specify depends_on for connectivity between front end and backend app in k8s

Tags: python, docker, nginx, kubernetes, docker-compose

I am trying to convert docker-compose to a native kubernetes manifest in my docker compose i have  depends_on for my nginx which depends upon the backend mysql and python app.

In kubernetes how do i map the connection from my nginx(a static site code inside /var/www/html/app) to backend python and mysql using the k8s service or ENV ??

Do i need to specify any connection string in my nginx web app (static site code) or can it be managed using the ENV or how does the connection work ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#accessing-the-service):

> Kubernetes supports 2 primary modes of finding a Service - environment
> variables and DNS. The former works out of the box while the latter
> requires the CoreDNS cluster addon.

So you don't have to hardcode it. Instead you can refer in your application code to kubernetes `Service` which exposes your backend `Pods` for other `Pods` inside your cluster.

If you decide to use [environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#environment-variables), remember that your `Service` must be created prior to your frontend `Pods` so the corresponding environment variables are set. If they were already running before you exposed your backend `Pods` via `ClusterIP` `Service`, no problem, you can recreate such `Pods` e.g. by scaling your `Deployment` in and out:

```
scale deployment my-nginx --replicas=0; kubectl scale deployment my-nginx --replicas=2;
```

If you've exposed your `python-backend` `Deployment` by running:

```
kubectl expose deployment python-backend
```

your `Service` will have the same name i.e. `python-backend`.

If you need to refer to it from any `Pod` in your cluster (e.g. frontend ones) you can use both ways:

[Environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#environment-variables):

```
$PYTHON_BACKEND_SERVICE_HOST:80
```

or even:

```
$PYTHON_BACKEND_SERVICE_HOST:$PYTHON_BACKEND_SERVICE_PORT
```

if you think your backend application port may change for some reason.

[DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#dns):

Use simply your `Service` name i.e. `python-backend` if both your frontend and backend `Pods` are running withing the same namespace or fully qualified domain name (FQDN) which has the following form:

```
<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

which in your case will be:

```
python-backend.default.svc.cluster.local
```

So having in mind that you added in your application code (or its configuration files) following connection strings:

either `$PYTHON_BACKEND_SERVICE_HOST:80` or `python-backend.default.svc.cluster.local:80`

you only need to remember to name your `Services` accordingly.